# Odd and Even numbers (using & or %)

Tags: php, operators

I've always used the following in order to find even and odd numbers:

```
if(   $num % 2  ) { echo "odd"; }
if( !($num % 2) ) { echo "even"; }
```

But recently I stumbled upon with the following code that works exactly the same:

```
if(   $num & 1  ) { echo "odd"; }
if( !($num & 1) ) { echo "even; }
```

What's the logic behind the "&" in the second method?

I went to check the [PHP: Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and the ampersand is not part of the options.

Thanks.

Comment: It's [a bitwise AND](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator.

Comment: You were just a couple of sections away: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php - it's a bitwise operator, not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the [bitwise-AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) operator.  Remember that in the computer, every integer is stored in binary form, and the lowest-significance binary digit is 2^0 == 1.  So, every odd number will have the lowest binary digit = 1.

So, the bitwise AND operator compares your value bit-by-bit with the constant `1`.  Bits that are `1` in both operands are set to `1` in the result, but bits that are `0` in *either* operand are set to `0` in the result.  The final result (which will be either `1` or `0`) is coerced to boolean by PHP because you are using it as the clause in an `if()` statement.

There is a very good reason for checking evenness with `&` instead of `%`: Speed!  The `%` operator requires a division operation so the remainder can be calculated, which is computationally much, much more expensive than just comparing the bits directly.

An example:

```
$num = 9;                // 9 == 8 + 1 == 2^3 + 2^0 == 1001b
echo (string)($num & 1); // 1001b & 0001b = 0001b - prints '1'

$num = 10;               // 10 == 8 + 2 == 2^3 + 2^1 == 1010b
echo (string)($num & 1); // 1010b & 0001b = 0000b - prints '0'
```

Comment: I was actually going to ask which option was the best (resource-wise), great answer.

Answer (score 9):

`&` is the binary `AND`.

The binary value of an odd number AND 1 will be 1, and the binary value of an even number AND 1 will be 0.

This happens because the binary value of an odd number always ends with 1 and the binary value of an even number ends with 0. So...

`10101101 & 00000001 = 00000001` in the case of an odd number and,

`10101100 & 00000000 = 00000000` in the case of an even number.